# changing input range color it changes right part to black

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, input

I'm trying to change input range color, but there is strange behaviour, when i change color to red (or some other like 'purple') it works as it should, but when changing it to '#CE7C00'(or many other colors such as 'yellow') then the right part of input becomes black, is there a way to remove that black ?

image of behaviour:

[image]

```css
.accent1 {
  accent-color: red;
}


.accent2 {
  accent-color: #CE7C00;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
     
      <input class="accent1" id="range" type="range">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="range-accent" class="accent2" type="range">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

> To prevent inaccessible elements from existing, browsers with
> accent-color need to determine an eligible contrast color to be used
> alongside the custom accent.

The background color changes because the browser tries to guarantee a certain amount of contrast between the background and the foreground. See [CSS accent-color](https://web.dev/accent-color/#guaranteeing-contrast).

Comment: is there any way to change color to '#CE7C00' and not have that black color ? without any javascript but just css

Comment: Not that i'm aware of for now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this the best way or not but You can use a linear gradient or any color you like on range input like this and change color dynamically using JavaScript
Its not actually changing color. It sets a cover on range input

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient

Note: You should change offset property using javascript

I Hope this was usefull for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).